# React, componentDidUpdate to fire second action, getting stuck in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to check if certain props changed, and if so fire an action, however right now I am stuck on it looping in on itself because it seems like the state does not update. I am not sure if i am trying to tap into the wrong life cycle event or taking the wrong approach, but here is what I have so far.

```
 componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(this.props.activeFilters != prevProps.activeFilters ) {
        //active filters have changed, fire search
        this.props.goToSearchResults("", this.props.activeFilters);
  }
 },
```

It is not updating the prevprops and I am wondering if there is a way I can just get this to fire once. I tried adding a line like :

```
 prevProps.activeFilters = this.props.activeFilters;
```

inside the if statement, but it gives me the error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'activeFilters' of #<Object>` which makes sense.

The basic idea is if those props change I would like to fire this event. What I was assuming though is that when it fires the goToSearchResults inside the if, the prevProps would get updated to the most current ones and this would only fire once.

What I am looking for is  *First Action ==> update active filters ==> listener catches this update and fires second action*. Any advice on how to approach this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does your `goToSearchResults` look like or the parent component?

Answer (score 1):

Try componentWillReceiveProps.

```js
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
  if(this.props.activeFilters != nextProps.activeFilters ) 
    //active filters have changed, fire search
    this.props.goToSearchResults("", this.props.activeFilters);
  }
}
```

Comment: Still loops in on itself

Comment: If the change is happening in the props then perhaps you should be doing this in the parent.

Comment: Ah ok, will give this a shot, Thanks!